# Node screenshot from chrome devtools is shifted to right

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I try to capture node screenshot from the chrome devtools, element which I want to capture is shifted to right in the screenshot. I am not sure why this happening, I tried googling this but I didn't get any fix. I have attached the screenshot of actual node and the screenshot taken from google devtools.

**Actual Node**

[image: Actual Node]

**Screenshot taken from chrome devtool**

[image: Screenshot taken from chrome devtool]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: This is freaking annoying.

Comment: Problem not found with Firefox 121.0.1 (64-bit). Problem exists with Microsoft Edge 120.0.2210.133(64-bit) and  google chrome 120.0.6099.217 (64-bit) .